# Select data from the database before or after a defined value

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems achieving the query to select data from a table in the db after a defined value has been met.

My code to do this is:

```
$fi = 'first_segment'
$im = popo.jpg

$sqls = "SELECT * FROM $fi,news_pictures
         WHERE $fi.pi_id = news_pictures.pi_id
           AND news_pictures.i_name = '$im'
         GROUP BY news_pictures.id DESC";
```

I wasn't able to achieve the result with that query.

Basically, I want the query to confirm if `news_pictures.i_name = '$im'` and if true, return starts from the value of `$im` followed by other data in the table depending on `news_pictures.id DESC`.

The sample data and output:

Table `news_pictures`:

```
id   i_name
--   ------
1    coco.jpg
2    lolo.jpg
3    popo.jpg
4    dodo.jpg
```

Since `$im = popo.jpg`, I want my query to display all values starting from `popo.jpg` with `id DESC`, i.e. `popo.jpg`, `lolo.jpg`, `coco.jpg`.

Comment: use mysql inner join

Answer (score 0):

I got to solve the question with the help of a friend.

```
$fsqls = "SELECT * FROM $fi,news_pictures WHERE $fi.pi_id = news_pictures.pi_id AND news_pictures.i_name = '$im' GROUP BY news_pictures.id";
$rres = mysqli_query($connection, $fsqls) or print(mysqli_error($connection));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rres))
{
    $rnm = $row["id"];
}
$sqls = "SELECT * FROM news_pictures WHERE news_pictures.id <= $rnm ORDER BY news_pictures.id DESC";
```